# Getting 400 bad request from firebase cloud database when attempting to send post request for push notifications in Android and retrofit2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit2, http-status-code-400

I'm relatively new to Android and I'm exploring new functions and APIs and I've been developing a simple chat app for quiet a few weeks to learn more stuff in android. So, I've been trying to implement notifications in my app and I've actually come up with quiet a few solutions. I tried using AlarmManagers but it didn't really work out well, so I resorted to FCM and I actually managed to push notifications through the FCM console, but when I tried to send a post request with a serialized body and title using Retrofit2, I got a 400 Bad Response code back from the server. I also tried using other codes that I found on GitHub and they all gave me the same response code.

ApiInterface Class:

```
public interface APIInterface {

 @Headers({"Authorization: key=AAAAcbbYIW4:APA91bHefWZnNKFoFhYRjDMVDMMp41-3zjt6RWcr_tku7NmvBEDDHDmZZCpfwc51rU-VlFsCMy_5dTp3YEN_3dvoDUPp1YRte7z1_iosdJwzS97VZ4wYjivgUT9VCe1f9_OGv",
    "Content-Type:application/json"})
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendNotification(@Body NotificationBody body);
}
```

Notification Body Class:

```
public class NotificationBody {

    @SerializedName("token")
    private String token;

    @SerializedName("notification")
    private NotificationContent notificationContent;

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public void setNotificationContent(NotificationContent notificationContent) {
        this.notificationContent = notificationContent;
    }
}
```

Notification Content:

```
public class NotificationContent {

     @SerializedName("title")
     String title;

     @SerializedName("body")
     String body;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Retrofit Client:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Firebase Token Class:

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
String token;
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        token = s;

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(firebaseUser!=null){
            updateToken(s);
        }
    }

    public void updateToken(String mToken){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TOKENS");
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        reference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(mToken);
    }  
}
```

I'm not sure if it's anything wrong with the Token generated or anything with my request body, I keep getting a 400 code no matter what. Can someone help me out?. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the 400 HTTP error because of the JSON structure you are sending as a payload is wrong. The correct structure is below one.

```
{
     "to": "<receiver_device_token_here>",
     "notification": {
         "title": "title for the notification"
         "body": "body for the notification"
     }
}
```

So, what's the mistake in your code? You used

```
 "token": "<receiver_device_token_here>"
```

instead of

```
 "to": "<receiver_device_token_here>"
```

Just change your `NotificationBody` POJO class like below

```
public class NotificationBody {

    @SerializedName("to")   //  <<======= CHANGE THE NAME FROM token TO to
    private String token;

    @SerializedName("notification")
    private NotificationContent notificationContent;

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public void setNotificationContent(NotificationContent notificationContent) {
        this.notificationContent = notificationContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to get the error log from retrofit's onSuccess response body and apparently it returned the following string: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@a84bd5a, I managed to parse it into a string using Gson and it returned the word 'to', did. So, this is what it meant :). It works for me now. Thank you so much for your help, I owe you one!